# How to Split NSArray in to Multi Line Strings

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

All,

I have a requirement where i have a NSArray arr = @[a,b,c,d]; Now i need to read from the Array and display it the form of multi line, How can we do that

a
b
c
d

Comment: just loop over it and print each value in a seperate line??

Comment: `componentsJoinedByString:` with the string `@"\n"`?

Comment: are you print on label ?

Comment: @Larme said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is

```
NSArray *persons = @[@"A", @"B", @"C",@"D"];
NSString *str = [persons componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"The str sis - %@",str);
```

The printed result is

```
The str sis - A
B
C
D
```